# how to force a has_many to use a specific :foreign_key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm having trouble with a model not honoring the :foreign_key policy.

Character model has the following fields: 
name:string
level:int
realm:string
realm_id:integer

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :realm

end
```

My Realms model looks like this:

```
class Realm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :characters, :foreign_key => "realm_id"

end
```

However, it seems like it's forcing the character model to use the :realm column as the foreign_key rather than :realm_id. I don't have any clue as to why or how to fix it. Is there any other way to make it ignore the :realm field and go for the :realm_id without having to change the name of the column?

**[Edit for clarity]**

The character model does have a realm_id:integer field. I have tried not having the foreign_key but the results with both is identical.

ruby-1.9.2-p136 :012 >   c = Character.new
 => #

ruby-1.9.2-p136 :013 > c.realm = "Sargeras"

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Realm(#2154038240) expected, got String(#2151988680)

Despite even having the foreign_key, it just refuses to let go of the realm column.

**[Edit 2]**

The realm column will just take over due to the has_many and belongs_to association. There is no way so far to break this, so the solution is to either remove the column (the approach i will take), or rename it to something different.

Comment: I tried this and I can't even create a Character object, because based on the association you made, Rails creates a method "realm" for Character, which refers to a Realm object. So I am unable to call c = Character.new(:realm => "wasteland") because it expects a Realm object for "realm", and not a string. Anyway, the more I look at your object model, I wonder if you are approaching things the right way. Why does a character have both a realm_id and a realm? Surely instead you should look up the realm information when you need it, based on the realm_id, and not store it in the Character model.

Comment: you talk about a field called realm on the realm model? call it something different and remove the foreign key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need the `:foreign_key` part here at all, since you're following the standard Rails naming convention, the realm_id column should be inferred from the model name.

**EDIT**

I see. I don't think you can have a column and an association by the same name in one model. The easiest solution would probably be to rename the "realm" column to "realmname" or something like that.

Comment: I have updated it. I removed the foreign_key, but it just refuses!

Comment: Thank you... I think that's the only way... I was really hoping that the foreign_key addition would force it to ignore the realm field. I'm importing this data from a different source which includes the realm, so I would rather not modify the data to keep it consistent and pretty. Either way, I will have to make changes to store the name or the id.

Your post was very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can get away without renaming the column by using alias_attribute - not sure. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-alias_attribute

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure that your Character table has a **realm_id** column? Please make sure of that, and then get rid of **foreign_key => 'realm_id**, it is not necessary at all. Your program should work if you get both these things done.

Comment: Yes I did.. It still doesn't like it.

Comment: I found your mistake. Here it is:

**ruby-1.9.2-p136 :013 > c.realm = "Sargeras"**

**ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Realm(#2154038240) expected, got String(#2151988680)**

Since you have **character** model that belongs to **realm** model, you should be assigning an object. so, you should be doing 

**@realm_obj = Realm.new**,
**c.realm = @realm_obj**

You are assigning a string when you should be assigning an object.

One more thing, your assignment should actually be:
**realm_obj.character = @character_obj**

as the Realm model **has** the Character model

Comment: You're still missing both the question and the problem. I realize it wants and object and that i'm feeding it a string (as it was posted on the original question). However, that is not the behavior that I wanted it to assume since I already have a realm_id which i will use to tie it up to the parent. Hence why i was trying to force it to use a foreign key rather than detect the field itself. 

I greatly appreciate the input but please consider reading the entire question and comments before answering. :)

Comment: hmm I guess. Anyways, I am glad that your problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

`belongs_to :realm` creates (among other things) methods called `realm` and `realm=` used as getters and setters. That means the method_missing magic that ActiveRecord uses to expose database columns as attributes is never triggered when you do Character#realm, as that method isn't in fact missing.

If you want to avoid renaming the realm column in your database, you could create attribute accessors for the field manually under another name:

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  def realm_name
    self['realm']
  end

  def realm_name=(value)
    self['realm'] = value
  end
end
```

This way you'll still have the realm column in your database and be able to access the attribute in Ruby, albeit under a different name. This isn't a great idea, though, as you'll be duplicating the realm name as both `Character#realm_name` and `Character.realm.name`.

I would ditch the `realm` column and instead make sure I use `Realm` objects when importing from the datasource:

```
character.realm = Realm.find_by_name('Sargeras')
```

That way you'd only realm data available where it makes sense; in the `Realm` model.

Comment: I pretty much arrived to this same conclusion and implemented the same solution. It is relieving to see a pro do that same thing :)


Ultimately ditched the realm column and implemented some methods to clean the hash so it can be inserted through build or create! I still think/argue that foreign_key should force it to ignore the realm field. I don't know how wrong i am, but it doesn't make sense to me to not honor the foreign_key request.

Comment: The `foreign_key` option is used to tell ActiveRecord what column to use when looking up associated models. It doesn't change the name of the association; you do that by, well, changing the name of the association - that is, the word after has_many or belongs_to.

In your case, the specified `foreign_key` *is* used when you do `realm.characters` and results in ActiveRecord generating SQL that says `FROM characters WHERE realm_id=42`. This happens to be exactly the same as the default, so the option isn't necessary.